# Material Design TextInputLayout With An Attached Dropdown?

Tags: android, kotlin, mobile, material-design, material-components-android

Is there a Material component that will easily let me set the left of a TextInputEditText to be a dropdown like this image below? If not, I can create something, but wanted to see if anyone knew more about Material components before I start doing too much custom work. Looks custom to me, though.


[image]

Comment: Use `AutoCompleteTextView` from the support/androidx/standard library in-place of `TextInputEditText` inside your `TextInputLayout`. See "Exposed dropdown menus" in https://material.io/develop/android/components/menu/

Comment: I know I can use AutoCompleteTextViews to get a drop-down menu. I was just wondering if there was a quick easy way to have these two components in one. As you will see, only the left side is a drop down and the right is a normal text input.

So I think it is safe to say that I was correct to assume this is more custom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far, both answers say to use AutoCompleteTextView. However, that doesn't answer my question. As you can see in the image I posted with the question, only the left side is a drop down. The right side is just a normal text input that isn't affected by the drop down.

However, I think it is safe to assume there isn't a component that will do this for me easily and that it would indeed be custom work to make these two components appear to be one single component.

Answer (score 0):

With material component, Google has removed spinner from its UI Elements.
Preferred way to do it is TextInputLayout along with AutoCompleteTextView just like Ashu has mentioned in the comment section.

Here is a more thorough article, which can help you in implementing AutoCompleteTextView.
https://blog.usejournal.com/there-is-no-material-design-spinner-for-android-3261b7c77da8

Comment: Lol, that's an awesome article. But yeah I know I can use spinners or AutoCompleteTextViews to get a drop-down menu. I was just wondering if there was a quick easy way to have these two components in one. As you will see, only the left side is a drop down and the right is a normal text input.